# PDO and executing code

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Just a quick question around executing PDO statements.

Below is my query

```
$setDate = "INSERT INTO wl_datecheck (inputdate) VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE($reportDate, '%Y%m%d')))";
```

Now, what I am doing is setting the query & connection as the variable $data as follows:

```
$data = $conn->query($setDate);
```

What I need to know, is does that ^^ alone execute or do I need to include

```
$data->execute();
```

The reason for asking is that I seem to be getting duplicate content from the INSERT statement & I'm not sure why

Comment: RTFM? http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are indeed doing it twice, you either use Query or Execute.

From the Docs:

> PDO::query() executes an SQL statement in a single function call,
> returning the result set (if any) returned by the statement as a
> PDOStatement object.
>
> For a query that you need to issue multiple times, you will realize
> better performance if you prepare a PDOStatement object using
> PDO::prepare() and issue the statement with multiple calls to
> PDOStatement::execute().

https://www.php.net/pdo.query

Comment: Thanks.  I had misinterpreted it!

Answer (score -1):

You can also simply check the result of the Insert statement by using [`rowCount()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

```
$data = $conn->query($setDate);
if($data->rowCount() >= 1){
 //echo "Inserted";
}else{
 //echo "An error occurred while inserting";
 //$arr = $data->errorInfo();
 //print_r($arr);
}
```

And no need to call `execute()`